# Оператор break c меткой в java

Tags: java, break

Всем здравствуйте, нужна пояснительная бригада, в процессе изучения Java по книге Г.Ш.
при изучении break label не понял выделенное: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLHEp.png
PS: разве можно указать оператор с которого продолжится выполнение программы ?
И можно вот пожалуйста примеров побольше.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как работает оператор break с меткой

Comment: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1389-operatorih-perekhoda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашей же книге есть идеальный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном коде `one, two, three` и есть те самые операторы, с которых программа продолжит свое выполнение. При срабатывании условия `if(i==1) break one;` программа продолжит выполнении с конца блока `one:`. Конец блока помеченный синим. При срабатывании `two` или `three` ситуация аналогичная. Места, с которого программа продолжит свое выполнение отмечена стрелками в цветах, в зависимости от того, какая метка сработает. Это своего рода аналогия оператора `goto` из других языков программирования. Но сразу скажу, данной конструкцией пользоваться нежелательно. Она нарушает структуру кода. В хорошем коде вы ее никогда не увидите. Поэтому прочитайте, ознакомьтесь, что такая есть, и двигайтесь дальше, не зацикливая на ней особого внимания.

Comment: Фраза продолжит выполнение меня настораживает, как бы говорит что сейчас будет открыт блок one,
потом блок two, потом блок three. А по факту мы переходим к System.out.println("После блока one");
Какая то подмена понятий.... Ну или перевод корявый.

Comment: @Dimka я там оговорился в ответе. Программа перейдет не на строку с one: а к концу блока, помеченного one.

Comment: Воистину, век живи - век учись, в том числе как не надо писать, так что поддерживаю совет НЕ пользоваться данной конструкцией :)  Её можно заменить обычным и более лаконичным вложенным циклом, где будет выводиться определенное количество строк в зависимости от значения `i`.